# ERROR: Flyway Teams Edition upgrade required: jdbc-secretsmanager is not supported by Flyway Community Edition

Tags: flyway, redgate

I am using flyway community edition v-7.0.4.
while trying to work it out with AWS jdbc-secretsmanager, ref. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/secretsManagement#dapr-secret-store, it throughs error ERROR: Flyway Teams Edition upgrade required: `jdbc-secretsmanager` is not supported by Flyway Community Edition
does AWS `secretsmanager` only supported for flyway teams which is commercial edition?

Thanks

Tried installing version 9 but have had same issue

Comment: That's exactly what the message tells you, in plain language. What part of *is not supported by Communication Edition* and *upgrade required* isn't clear?

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite, I was expecting if someone else has faced similar issue and has got any hack for free :) , without upgrading it to flyway team commercial edition.

Comment: When something is not supported, it usually means that the code to support it is not there, so there wouldn't be a hack. And if there was, using it would most likely violate their Terms of Service (TOS) and, if you were caught, subject you to legal risk. When a large company comes after someone with a legal team, it typically gets very expensive for the person they're after, because if you lose you're liable for all legal fees (including theirs) under the TOS. And that TOS also requires things to happen in their jurisdiction.